# How to calculate derivative of $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2\cos^2x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2\cos^2x}$$

The result of $f'(x)$ should be equals

$$f'(x) = \frac{-4\cos x\sin x}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2}$$

I'm trying to do it in this way but my result is wrong.

$$f'(x) =  \frac {1'(1-2\cos x)-1(1-2\cos^2x)'}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2} = 
\frac {1-2\cos^2x-(1-(2\cos^2x)')}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2} = $$

$$=\frac {-2\cos^2x + 2(2\cos x(\cos x)')}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2} = 
\frac {-2\cos^2x+2(-2\sin x\cos x)}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2} = $$

$$\frac {-2\cos^2x-4\sin x\cos x}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2}$$

Comment: What is the derivative of 1? You evaluated it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative of the function that is constantly $1$ should be zero, not $1$.

Comment: Yeah, I've forgotten about that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{1-2\cos^2 x}=-\dfrac{1}{2\cos^2 x-1}=-\dfrac{1}{\cos 2x}=-\sec 2x$

$\therefore f'(x)=-2\sec(2x)\tan(2x) \quad\blacksquare$

Check the list of formulas for finding derivatives of trigonometric functions [here](http://www.math.com/tables/derivatives/more/trig.htm)

Comment: I think my approach is simpler (at least for me).

Comment: THEN I HAVE NOTHING TO SAY.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the quotient formula for functions of the form $1/g(x)$. Rather consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1-2\cos^2x}=\frac{1}{g(x)}
$$
where $g(x)=1-2\cos^2x$. Since $\Bigl(\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigr)'=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, you have, by the chain rule,
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{1}{g(x)^2}g'(x)
$$
and
$$
g'(x)=4\sin x\cos x,
$$
so
$$
f'(x)=-\frac{4\sin x\cos x}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this step, from here

$$f'(x) =  \frac {1'(1-2\cos x)-1(1-2\cos^2x)'}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2} $$
to here
$$\frac {1-2\cos^2x-(1-(2\cos^2x)')}{(1-2\cos^2x)^2}$$

because $$1'=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-2cos^2x}$

The result of $f'(x)$ should be equal $f'(x) = \frac{-4cosxsinx}{(1-2cos^2x)^2}$

$$
f'(x) = 
\frac {0-1(1-2cos^2x)'}  {(1-2cos^2x)^2} =

\frac {-4sinxcosx}          {(1-2cos^2x)^2}
$$